# Calculating image brightness using BGR color and B channel

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I was trying to calculate if an image is bright or dark using mean value and by mistake I forgot to convert my BGR image to LAB and extract the LAB channel. Instead I extracted the B channel in BGR image. What surprised me when I tested this method in my labeled images it shows high accuracy, recall and precision. So when I tried to show the image to check what color it is, it shows a grayscale image (I'm not sure why I expected an image with more blue color). When I read about BGR and calculating brightness of an image it always mentioned calculating the mean value for all the channels. So how is this possible?

The images are of underwater environment

```
img = cv2.imread("image.jpg")
#conv_image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
l_channel, _, _ = cv2.split(img)
img = l_channel

cv2.imshow("Result", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Consider the BGR representation of a greyscale image – each of the channels is the same, so `B = G = R = mean(B,G,R)`, so you could use any of those channels as the brightness. It's plausible that in your underwater environment, the values are essentially monochromatic albeit with a blue bias, e.g. `G = R = B / 2 - 50`. In this case, the blue channel (and the other channels) would still be strongly correlated with the mean and the brightness.

Comment: Just having a high blue value does not guarantee that the color of that pixel is bluish, it depends on the other chsnnels as well. On the other hand, if the pixel is bluish, the G and R channel values are guaranteed to be rather low (conpared to rhe B channel).